# separating values by delimiter in rows PowerBI, does each row lose its Unique ID?

Tags: powerbi

I'm currently cleaning up a csv and building a dashboard, I've mostly completed it, but run into an issue where I have multiple columns with yes/no valuies in the CSV making it difficult to report on, so I have:

```
Which Access Point: Main Website, Which Access Point: Blog, (+30 columns)
                              Yes                      Yes
```

This could go on for twenty to thirty columns, so I've cleaned this up using Pandas/Python by creating a new column, changing the yes value into something more readable into one cell.

so you would have

```
Which Access?
Main_website, blog, twitter, facebook
```

so, splitting these by commas in rows (in PowerBI) would allow me to make a very user-friendly dashboard.

Now, what I want will the dashboard work with other bits of data correctly?

for example can I still find out how many people in company x with y role accessed the website via twitter using the filters/slicers?

Apologies if this doesn't make sense, I've just got my hands on PowerBI yesterday and quite new to the world of data in general.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of data! There is so much work to do and so few of us, so lets get cracking ...

I would open the Query Editor, select the **Which Access** column and use the **Split Column** button, choosing **By Delimiter**.  The Delimiter would be comma obviously, then under the **Advanced options** I would choose **Rows**.

This will generate one row for each comma-separated value, with all the other column values (e.g. company, role) repeated as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks, the last sentence answered my query perfectly! thanks for the welcome I'll be frequenting these parts quite often!

Comment: Good to hear.  Eventually you will have to find a new username though ...

Comment: Ha! I guess I should move up the noble status of Datasquire! Regardless, I've tested this out now on my dashboard and it worked beautifully! My python script to clean up the data on the other hand is far from beautiful! Thanks for your help!